# How to web asp.net web service call exe?

Tags: asp.net, service

I try to call exe from web service. It can not run exe programme. 
anyone please help me for this problem.
I develope it by asp.net.

Thank you for this so much.

Asada

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("filename of the exe file");
```